# Rank N types in let bindings

Tags: haskell, gadt

So I've done this...

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, GADTs  #-}

type Record fields = forall t. fields t -> t

data PersonField t where
    Name :: PersonField String
    Age :: PersonField Int
type Person = Record PersonField
```

And then this...

```
nigel :: Person
nigel Name = "Nigel"
nigel Age = 39
```

And it all seems to work as expected.

What I'm struggling with is how to define a Person value inside a let binding. For example this doesn't work:

```
abigail :: Person
abigail = let x Name = "Abigail"
              x Age = 27 
           in x
```

Gives me:

> Couldn't match expected type `t1' with actual type `[Char]'
>    `t1' is untouchable ...

Is there a way to make this work inside a let binding?

Comment: I think you need to add a type annotation inside the `let` e.g. `let x :: Person ; x Name = "Abigail" ; x Age = 27`.

Comment: That does it. Thanks! If you make the comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need explicit type annotations when GADTs are involved:

```
abigail :: Person
abigail = let x :: Person
              x Name = "Abigail"
              x Age = 27 
           in x
```

Without it, GHC roughly sees

```
let x Name = "Abigail"
```

and says "OK, `x` is a function from the type of `Name`, i.e. `PersonField String` to the type of `"Abigail"`, i.e. `String`. In the next line,

```
let x Name = "Abigail"
    x Age = 27
```

GHC now finds out `x` to accept also a `PersonField Int` and to return a number. This clashes with the previously inferred type, triggering a type error.

With an explicit type annotation, type inference will not try to infer a wrong type for `x`: it was provided by the user. Instead, only type checking will be performed.